# How to visualize surface normal of kinect data using PCL in ROS?

Tags: c++, ros, point-cloud-library, kinect-v2

I am trying to get surface normal from my kinect2 data using PCL in ROS. I am having trouble in visualizing normal data.

I am using [Following Viewer](https://github.com/dirkholz/pcl_online_viewer/tree/master/src) to view real time point cloud.

I have added [point normal code](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/normal_estimation_using_integral_images.php#normal-estimation-using-integral-images) of PCL to this code to calculate and visualize normal.

I am getting following runtime error:

```
ERROR: In /home/chandan_main/Downloads/VTK-7.1.0/Rendering/OpenGL2/vtkOpenGLPolyDataMapper.cxx, line 1794
vtkOpenGLPolyDataMapper (0xa1ea5e0): failed after UpdateShader 1 OpenGL errors detected
  0 : (1281) Invalid value


[pcl::IntegralImageNormalEstimation::setInputCloud] Input dataset is not organized (height = 1).
[pcl::IntegralImageNormalEstimation::initCompute] Input dataset is not organized (height = 1).
[addPointCloudNormals] The number of points differs from the number of normals!
[pcl::IntegralImageNormalEstimation::setInputCloud] Input dataset is not organized (height = 1).
[pcl::IntegralImageNormalEstimation::initCompute] Input dataset is not organized (height = 1).
[addPointCloudNormals] The number of points differs from the number of normals!
[pcl::IntegralImageNormalEstimation::setInputCloud] Input dataset is not organized (height = 1).
[pcl::IntegralImageNormalEstimation::initCompute] Input dataset is not organized (height = 1).
[addPointCloudNormals] The number of points differs from the number of normals!
```

Comment: Could you post the actual code you've included into your viewer? It seems like you didn't properly set your input cloud; or that Kinect2 data are not organized (in which case you can't use the normal estimation with integral images but use the "regular" method of normal estimation in PCL).

Comment: I am able to get the normal now...I have  just used   while(!viewer->wasStopped())
  {
    viewer->spinOnce (100);
    boost::this_thread::sleep (boost::posix_time::microseconds (100000));
  } becuse I was trying to get normal in real time...It was showing errors...I also rebuilt VTK library which had issues

Answer (score 0):

I am able to get the normal now.I have just used

while(!viewer->wasStopped()) 
{ 
viewer->spinOnce (100); boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::microseconds (100000));
 }

becuse I was trying to get normal in real time.It was showing errors.I also rebuilt VTK library which had issues.